# Problema c/ swapcaser em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

O programa deve converter uma letra no esquema A->a ou a->A e funciona normalmente, exceto que no final da string surge um None. Alguém sabe como posso tira-lo?

```
def swap_case(s):
for x in s:
    if x.isupper()==True:
        print(x.lower(), end="")
    else:
        print(x.upper(), end="")
s = input('Digite: ')
result = swap_case(s)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surge um `None` pois tu não estás a retornar nada na tua função, só estás a imprimir, altera para:

```
def swap_case(s):
    for x in s:
        if x.isupper()==True:
            return x.lower()
        else:
            return x.upper()
s = input('Digite: ')
result = swap_case(s)
print(result, end="")
```

Aproveitando para melhorar:

1- A função `isupper` já retorna um `True` ou `False` (é *boolean*), logo isto `if x.isupper()==True:` pode/deve ficar só `if x.isupper():`

2- (MAIS IMPORTANTE) A função não parece fazer muito sentido assim (vai retornar só a primeira letra trocada), porque o que tu deves querer com "*swap_case*" é trocar todas as letras da string fornecida, logo assim não faz sentido, o que deves querer é:

```
def swap_case(s):
    text = ''
    for x in s:
        if x.isupper():
            text += x.lower()
        else:
            text += x.upper()
    return text

s = input('Digite: ')
result = swap_case(s)
print(result)
```

> Input: nElSoN
>   Output: NeLsOn

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/AffectionateVoluminousChevrotain)

Reduzindo para uma linha dentro da função:

```
def swap_case(s):
    return ''.join(x.lower() if x.isupper() else x.upper() for x in s)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/LightyellowEcstaticLeopard)

Comment: cool! +1 ...e já agora; `return "".join([chr(ord(x)^32) for x in s])`

Comment: @JJoao Boa, assim também é cool